# Codeigniter pagination with filters and performance

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, limit, offset

i'm having trouble with CI pagination this is my code.

the controller:

```
$per_page = 20;
$offset = $this->uri->segment(2); 
$results = $this->model_users->search($keywords,$limit = $per_page,$offset,$order_by,$expire,$type = $q_type);

$pagination['per_page'] = $per_page;
$pagination['base_url'] = site_url('users');
$pagination['first_url'] = site_url('users');
$pagination['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('ci_users');
$pagination['uri_segment'] = 2;
$pagination['first_link'] = 'First';
$pagination['last_link'] = 'Last';
$pagination['next_link']  = false;
$pagination['prev_link']  = false;
$pagination['num_links'] = 6;

$this->pagination->initialize($pagination);


$view['users'] = $results;
```

the model:

```
function search($keywords = false,$limit = false,$offset=false,$order_by = false,$expire = false,$type = 'get'){

 if($keywords){
   $this->db->select("*,
           MATCH(".$type.") 
           AGAINST ('".$keywords."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
            AS _score",false /*important*/);
   $this->db->having('_score > 0');
   $this->db->from('ci_users');
  $this->db->order_by('_score','DESC');
}else{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('ci_users');
}
  if($expire){

  $this->db->order_by('expire_datetime',$expire);
  }
  if($order_by){
  $this->db->order_by("id",$order_by);
 }

  if($limit){
  $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
}

 $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();

}
```

When i click on link1 or link2 everythings is ok, when i click on link3 no results returns and don't understand why.

Using this code it fixes, but it is not good for site performance cause i'm running 2 search queries at same time :

```
 $pagination['total_rows'] = count($this->model_propos->search($keywords,false,false,false ,false,$type = $q_type));
```

thanks to who will help me !!

Comment: because you are taking $pagination['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('ci_users'); this is all records of table but it should only total records of matching keywords as per your search.

Comment: site_url('users/') try that > and use uri_segment= 3

Comment: @GBD so for a simple search i need to run search 2 times? is this only for CI or also for all the others frameworks out there? :O

Comment: yup. 2 times.... you are doing 2 queries anyway already. It won't make any difference in number of times.

Comment: @itachi undrstood ... but ... what if site has milion's users?? 2 search for each users? :/

Comment: can't i add to the first query some count field and use that in pagination?

Comment: 1st of all, if the site has millions of users, then CI is not a good choice. 2nd, learn caching.

Comment: @itachi uhmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm ... mmmmmmmmmmmmm ... sure is the only way that? does is better to do 2 queries or only 1 and split results by php?

Comment: You must do 2 queries. (whether it is subquery or main does not matter). You can't use LIMIT and get all the results simultaneously. And how you can split results by PHP? Lets say you got all the results.... then split it. 1st page shown.... OK. till now it is ok. What about the other pages? From where you will get those results?

Comment: @itachi i can do that but i need to retrieve for each page all the results, check http://pastebin.com/Mu6GrSgv , just don't know if is better or not

Comment: for checking how i can split results in php, and not, in sql by limit

Comment: you have an undefined variable `$populateTerms` there.

Comment: oops missed that. Now think logically. There are millions of datas from millions of users. In each time, you made this call, you are populating `populateTerms` with all those datas only to keep 50 or 100.... Do you really think it will be any faster? it is a wastage plus does not serve any purpose because each time, you are fetching datas of which, probably you will dump 95%.

Comment: i think the main problem is catching who will be faster splitting all the results, sql or php?

Comment: it can't be answered in straight forward way because lots of variables involved. What type of caching, how you will cache, what amount of cache, what will be the desgin of cache, how many users you are expecting.... ist goes on and on. That's a whole different topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as has been explained what's happening is you're counting all the records but then returning a filtered result set. What you need to do is count only the filtered results. This is pretty easy to accomplish by simply changing the total_rows, thankfully your query is already set up to do this by having the defaults set in the function itself.

```
$pagination['total_rows'] = $this->db->count($this->model_users->search($keywords));
```

That is going to return a count of just the result set including your keywords which is the actual count you want for the pagination to work.

You may have to change the if statement in the model to return a full record set to:

```
if($keywords && keywords != '')
```

But you'll have to test that one.